# Microsoft Expression Web 4, blank space between lines of code

Tags: html, ide, code-formatting

Every time I open my website to edit, there are more blank lines between my code. I delete the blank spaces (which takes forever) and close MEW4 and when I re-open it the next day, there are more spaces. Hundreds and hundreds of extra lines. This does not affect the look of the website when opened in a browser, it is just extremely difficult to edit when I have to constantly scroll through hundreds of blank lines in between my code. What could be causing this?

http://www.centercitycondos.com/just_listed.htm

This page is the one I edit the most and is the worst offender. Here is a screenshot of the code where its not too bad but you can see as the page goes on, there are more and more lines in between:

[image: blank spaces starting to form]

As I scroll down, the whole screen is blank for hundreds of lines in between each line of code.
Anyone have any ideas? I'm desperate to fix this.

Comment: You might find these informative: [blank line between code lines](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/c21b600a-2463-4f88-b8a6-5c30923d854c/blank-line-between-code-lines?forum=web) and [Expression Web Adds lines and spaces in html view!](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/ce9979a2-7c59-4a28-b05c-bbdd095e5717/expression-web-adds-lines-and-spaces-in-html-view?forum=web)

Answer (score 0):

You go to Edit > Replace in the Expression Web menu.

Then, you select the “Replace” tab and insert ^\n in the “Find what” space. In the “Replace with” space, you leave blank.

Finally, you go below to the “Advanced section” and check "Regular expressions", and click the button “Replace all”.

That´s it.

Comment: Wow! Amazing. Thank you so much!